# Winforms: "The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process"

Tags: c#, winforms, file

I'm making a WinForms program that includes a part where you can open a file, write some data to it, and then save it. I've made two buttons that are linked to an `OpenFileDialog` and a `SaveFileDialog`, respectively. When you don't use the "Open..." button and save a new file, it works fine. However, attempting to write to an existing file brings up a dialog box that says the error mentioned in the title. The two functions I suspect, both event handler functions for the buttons, are included below.

```
// button1 is the "Open..." button

public void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            using (Stream stream = openFileDialog1.OpenFile())
            {
                using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream))
                {
                    textBox1.Text = reader.ReadToEnd();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

As well as:

```
public void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        saveFileDialog1 = new SaveFileDialog();
        string filePath = openFileDialog1.FileName;
        if (filePath == "")
        {
            if (saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                using (StreamWriter saveStream = new StreamWriter(saveFileDialog1.FileName, false))
                {
                    saveStream.Write(textBox1.Text);
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            using (StreamWriter existingFileSave = new StreamWriter(filePath, false))
            {
                File.WriteAllText(filePath, String.Empty);
                existingFileSave.Write(textBox1.Text);
            }
        }
    }
```

I've tried putting every file operation in a `using` block so that each file is explicitly closed. It has no effect. I suspect the issue is that somehow, the `OpenFileDialog` doesn't actually close, as it isn't exactly a file. Do you have any advice on how to "close" it, or any other solution that would fix this bug?
I've looked for solutions elsewhere on this platform, but none of them have to do with the `OpenFileDialog`.

Comment: All modal dialogs (Forms you show with `ShowDialog()`) should be declared with an `using` statement. Avoid this: `string filePath = openFileDialog1.FileName;`, store the last file name in a Field / class Property / whatever) -- The weird part is: `File.WriteAllText(filePath, String.Empty);
existingFileSave.Write(textBox1.Text);` ?? Pick one or the other. You can use just `File.WriteAllText()` / `File.ReadAllText()`, these methods open and close a Stream for you

Comment: `File.WriteAllText` is trying to open the file that you just opened by creating a stream on it. As Jimi said: just use `File.WriteAllText(filePath, textBox1.Text);`

Comment: @Jimi Yeah, I thought I could use that to wipe out the contents of the file before writing to it and it would just automatically close. I guess you have to add a `.Close` to it or something. This is my second WinForms app, but I'm fine at normal C#. I don't really know why I did that.

Comment: Hopw is WINFORMS here relevant? Want to tag your preferred pizza? Winforms is UI - WINFORMS is not doing your files, that is pure .NET code.

Comment: @TomTom Well, I thought the issue was because of the `OpenFileDialog` but it was not. It was just a bad logic issue.

Comment: That makes NO sense. Besides being trivial to test for you - the dialog returns a NAME, not a file, why the heck would it OPEN THE FILE?

Comment: @TomTom I have no idea, I'm really not the best at this language.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, in response to the commenters (@Jimi and @Fildor) I changed that part of the code to `File.WriteAllText(filePath, textBox1.Text)` and it works! Thank you to the users previously mentioned.